# Compass grid mixin generating over 16,000 characters of CSS

Tags: sass, mixins, compass-sass

Today I installed Compass and thought I'd try to generate a grid background to help me line things up.

I checked the docs (http://compass-style.org/reference/compass/layout/grid_background/#mixin-grid-background), and it couldn't be simpler, all I need to write is:

```
body{
    @include grid-background;
}
```

and SASS will produce the correct CSS. My terminal told me everything had gone to plan. Great. I go to my browser to check out the grid, and it looks a little glitchy. So I open up dev tools to look at the css, and to my horror I see over 16000 characters of CSS....

```
body {
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, 50% 100%, 50% 0%, color-stop(5%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)), color-stop(5%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0))), -webkit-gradient(linear, 0% 50%, 960 50%, color-stop(0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)), color-stop(0%, rgba(100, 100, 225, 0.25)), color-stop(3.125%, rgba(100, 100, 225, 0.25)), color-stop(3.125%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)), color-stop(4.16667%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)), color-stop(4.16667%, rgba(100, 100, 225, 0.25)), color-stop(7.29167%, rgba(100, 100, 225, 0.25)), color-stop(7.29167%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)), color-stop(8.33333%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)), color-stop(8.33333%, rgba(100, 100, 225, 0.25)), color-stop(11.45833%, rgba(100, 100, 225, 0.25)), color-stop(11.45833%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)), color-stop(12.5%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)), color-stop(12.5%, rgba(100, 100, 225, 0.25)), color-stop(15.625%, rgba(100, 100, 225, 0.25)), color-stop(15.625%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)), color-stop(16.66667%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)), color-stop(16.66667%, rgba(100, 100, 225, 0.25)), color-stop(19.79167%, rgba(100, 100, 225, 0.25)), color-stop(19.79167%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)), color-stop(20.83333%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)), color-stop(20.83333%, rgba(100, 100, 225, 0.25)), color-stop(23.95833%, rgba(100, 100, 225, 0.25)), color-stop(23.95833%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)), color-stop(25%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)), color-stop(25%, rgba(100, 100, 225, 0.25)), color-stop(28.125%, rgba(100, 100, 225, 0.25)), color-stop(28.125%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)), color-stop(29.16667%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)), color-stop(29.16667%, rgba(100, 100, 225, 0.25)), color-stop(32.29167%, rgba(100, 100, 225, 0.25)), color-stop(32.29167%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)), color-stop(33.33333%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)), color-stop(33.33333%, rgba(100, 100, 225, 0.25)), color-stop(36.45833%, rgba(100, 100, 225, 0.25)), color-stop(36.45833%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)), color-stop(37.5%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)), color-stop(37.5%, rgba(100, 100, 225, 0.25)), color-stop(40.625%, rgba(100, 100, 225, 0.25)), color-stop(40.625%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)), color-stop(41.66667%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)), color-stop(41.66667%, rgba(100, 100, 225, 0.25)), color-stop(44.79167%, rgba(100, 100, 225, 0.25)), color-stop(44.79167%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)), color-stop(45.83333%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)), color-stop(45.83333%, rgba(100, 100, 225, 0.25)), color-stop(48.95833%, rgba(100, 100, 225, 0.25)), color-stop(48.95833%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)), color-stop(50%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)), color-stop(50%, rgba(100, 100, 225, 0.25)), color-stop(53.125%, rgba(100, 100, 225, 0.25)), color-stop(53.125%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)), color-stop(54.16667%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)), color-stop(54.16667%, rgba(100, 100, 225, 0.25)), color-stop(57.29167%, rgba(100, 100, 225, 0.25)), color-stop(57.29167%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)), color-stop(58.33333%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)), color-stop(58.33333%, rgba(100, 100, 225, 0.25)), color-stop(61.45833%, rgba(100, 100, 225, 0.25)), color-stop(61.45833%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)), color-stop(62.5%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)), color-stop(62.5%, rgba(100, 100, 225, 0.25)), color-stop(65.625%, rgba(100, 100, 225, 0.25)), color-stop(65.625%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)), color-stop(66.66667%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)), color-stop(66.66667%, rgba(100, 100, 225, 0.25)), color-stop(69.79167%, rgba(100, 100, 225, 0.25)), color-stop(69.79167%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)), color-stop(70.83333%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)), color-stop(70.83333%, rgba(100, 100, 225, 0.25)), color-stop(73.95833%, rgba(100, 100, 225, 0.25)), color-stop(73.95833%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)), color-stop(75%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)), color-stop(75%, rgba(100, 100, 225, 0.25)), color-stop(78.125%, rgba(100, 100, 225, 0.25)), color-stop(78.125%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)), color-stop(79.16667%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)), color-stop(79.16667%, rgba(100, 100, 225, 0.25)), color-stop(82.29167%, rgba(100, 100, 225, 0.25)), color-stop(82.29167%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)), color-stop(83.33333%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)), color-stop(83.33333%, rgba(100, 100, 225, 0.25)), color-stop(86.45833%, rgba(100, 100, 225, 0.25)), color-stop(86.45833%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)), color-stop(87.5%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)), color-stop(87.5%, rgba(100, 100, 225, 0.25)), color-stop(90.625%, rgba(100, 100, 225, 0.25)), color-stop(90.625%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)), color-stop(91.66667%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)), color-stop(91.66667%, rgba(100, 100, 225, 0.25)), color-stop(94.79167%, rgba(100, 100, 225, 0.25)), color-stop(94.79167%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)), color-stop(95.83333%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)), color-stop(95.83333%, rgba(100, 100, 225, 0.25)), color-stop(98.95833%, rgba(100, 100, 225, 0.25)), color-stop(98.95833%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)), color-stop(100%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)));
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(bottom, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) 5%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 5%), -webkit-linear-gradient(left, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 0px, rgba(100, 100, 225, 0.25) 0px, rgba(100, 100, 225, 0.25) 30px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 30px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 40px, rgba(100, 100, 225, 0.25) 40px, rgba(100, 100, 225, 0.25) 70px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 70px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 80px, rgba(100, 100, 225, 0.25) 80px, rgba(100, 100, 225, 0.25) 110px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 110px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 120px, rgba(100, 100, 225, 0.25) 120px, rgba(100, 100, 225, 0.25) 150px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 150px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 160px, rgba(100, 100, 225, 0.25) 160px, rgba(100, 100, 225, 0.25) 190px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 190px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 200px, rgba(100, 100, 225, 0.25) 200px, rgba(100, 100, 225, 0.25) 230px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 230px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 240px, rgba(100, 100, 225, 0.25) 240px, rgba(100, 100, 225, 0.25) 270px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 270px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 280px, rgba(100, 100, 225, 0.25) 280px, rgba(100, 100, 225, 0.25) 310px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 310px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 320px, rgba(100, 100, 225, 0.25) 320px, rgba(100, 100, 225, 0.25) 350px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 350px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 360px, rgba(100, 100, 225, 0.25) 360px, rgba(100, 100, 225, 0.25) 390px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 390px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 400px, rgba(100, 100, 225, 0.25) 400px, rgba(100, 100, 225, 0.25) 430px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 430px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 440px, rgba(100, 100, 225, 0.25) 440px, rgba(100, 100, 225, 0.25) 470px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 470px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 480px, rgba(100, 100, 225, 0.25) 480px, rgba(100, 100, 225, 0.25) 510px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 510px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 520px, rgba(100, 100, 225, 0.25) 520px, rgba(100, 100, 225, 0.25) 550px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 550px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 560px, rgba(100, 100, 225, 0.25) 560px, rgba(100, 100, 225, 0.25) 590px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 590px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 600px, rgba(100, 100, 225, 0.25) 600px, rgba(100, 100, 225, 0.25) 630px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 630px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 640px, rgba(100, 100, 225, 0.25) 640px, rgba(100, 100, 225, 0.25) 670px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 670px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 680px, rgba(100, 100, 225, 0.25) 680px, rgba(100, 100, 225, 0.25) 710px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 710px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 720px, rgba(100, 100, 225, 0.25) 720px, rgba(100, 100, 225, 0.25) 750px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 750px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 760px, rgba(100, 100, 225, 0.25) 760px, rgba(100, 100, 225, 0.25) 790px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 790px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 800px, rgba(100, 100, 225, 0.25) 800px, rgba(100, 100, 225, 0.25) 830px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 830px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 840px, rgba(100, 100, 225, 0.25) 840px, rgba(100, 100, 225, 0.25) 870px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 870px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 880px, rgba(100, 100, 225, 0.25) 880px, rgba(100, 100, 225, 0.25) 910px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 910px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 920px, rgba(100, 100, 225, 0.25) 920px, rgba(100, 100, 225, 0.25) 950px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 950px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 960px);
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(bottom, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) 5%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 5%), -moz-linear-gradient(left, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 0px, rgba(100, 100, 225, 0.25) 0px, rgba(100, 100, 225, 0.25) 30px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 30px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 40px, rgba(100, 100, 225, 0.25) 40px, rgba(100, 100, 225, 0.25) 70px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 70px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 80px, rgba(100, 100, 225, 0.25) 80px, rgba(100, 100, 225, 0.25) 110px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 110px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 120px, rgba(100, 100, 225, 0.25) 120px, rgba(100, 100, 225, 0.25) 150px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 150px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 160px, rgba(100, 100, 225, 0.25) 160px, rgba(100, 100, 225, 0.25) 190px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 190px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 200px, rgba(100, 100, 225, 0.25) 200px, rgba(100, 100, 225, 0.25) 230px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 230px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 240px, rgba(100, 100, 225, 0.25) 240px, rgba(100, 100, 225, 0.25) 270px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 270px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 280px, rgba(100, 100, 225, 0.25) 280px, rgba(100, 100, 225, 0.25) 310px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 310px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 320px, rgba(100, 100, 225, 0.25) 320px, rgba(100, 100, 225, 0.25) 350px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 350px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 360px, rgba(100, 100, 225, 0.25) 360px, rgba(100, 100, 225, 0.25) 390px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 390px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 400px, rgba(100, 100, 225, 0.25) 400px, rgba(100, 100, 225, 0.25) 430px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 430px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 440px, rgba(100, 100, 225, 0.25) 440px, rgba(100, 100, 225, 0.25) 470px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 470px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 480px, rgba(100, 100, 225, 0.25) 480px, rgba(100, 100, 225, 0.25) 510px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 510px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 520px, rgba(100, 100, 225, 0.25) 520px, rgba(100, 100, 225, 0.25) 550px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 550px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 560px, rgba(100, 100, 225, 0.25) 560px, rgba(100, 100, 225, 0.25) 590px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 590px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 600px, rgba(100, 100, 225, 0.25) 600px, rgba(100, 100, 225, 0.25) 630px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 630px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 640px, rgba(100, 100, 225, 0.25) 640px, rgba(100, 100, 225, 0.25) 670px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 670px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 680px, rgba(100, 100, 225, 0.25) 680px, rgba(100, 100, 225, 0.25) 710px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 710px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 720px, rgba(100, 100, 225, 0.25) 720px, rgba(100, 100, 225, 0.25) 750px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 750px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 760px, rgba(100, 100, 225, 0.25) 760px, rgba(100, 100, 225, 0.25) 790px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 790px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 800px, rgba(100, 100, 225, 0.25) 800px, rgba(100, 100, 225, 0.25) 830px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 830px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 840px, rgba(100, 100, 225, 0.25) 840px, rgba(100, 100, 225, 0.25) 870px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 870px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 880px, rgba(100, 100, 225, 0.25) 880px, rgba(100, 100, 225, 0.25) 910px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 910px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 920px, rgba(100, 100, 225, 0.25) 920px, rgba(100, 100, 225, 0.25) 950px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 950px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 960px);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(bottom, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) 5%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 5%), -o-linear-gradient(left, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 0px, rgba(100, 100, 225, 0.25) 0px, rgba(100, 100, 225, 0.25) 30px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 30px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 40px, rgba(100, 100, 225, 0.25) 40px, rgba(100, 100, 225, 0.25) 70px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 70px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 80px, rgba(100, 100, 225, 0.25) 80px, rgba(100, 100, 225, 0.25) 110px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 110px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 120px, rgba(100, 100, 225, 0.25) 120px, rgba(100, 100, 225, 0.25) 150px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 150px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 160px, rgba(100, 100, 225, 0.25) 160px, rgba(100, 100, 225, 0.25) 190px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 190px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 200px, rgba(100, 100, 225, 0.25) 200px, rgba(100, 100, 225, 0.25) 230px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 230px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 240px, rgba(100, 100, 225, 0.25) 240px, rgba(100, 100, 225, 0.25) 270px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 270px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 280px, rgba(100, 100, 225, 0.25) 280px, rgba(100, 100, 225, 0.25) 310px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 310px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 320px, rgba(100, 100, 225, 0.25) 320px, rgba(100, 100, 225, 0.25) 350px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 350px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 360px, rgba(100, 100, 225, 0.25) 360px, rgba(100, 100, 225, 0.25) 390px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 390px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 400px, rgba(100, 100, 225, 0.25) 400px, rgba(100, 100, 225, 0.25) 430px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 430px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 440px, rgba(100, 100, 225, 0.25) 440px, rgba(100, 100, 225, 0.25) 470px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 470px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 480px, rgba(100, 100, 225, 0.25) 480px, rgba(100, 100, 225, 0.25) 510px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 510px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 520px, rgba(100, 100, 225, 0.25) 520px, rgba(100, 100, 225, 0.25) 550px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 550px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 560px, rgba(100, 100, 225, 0.25) 560px, rgba(100, 100, 225, 0.25) 590px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 590px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 600px, rgba(100, 100, 225, 0.25) 600px, rgba(100, 100, 225, 0.25) 630px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 630px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 640px, rgba(100, 100, 225, 0.25) 640px, rgba(100, 100, 225, 0.25) 670px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 670px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 680px, rgba(100, 100, 225, 0.25) 680px, rgba(100, 100, 225, 0.25) 710px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 710px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 720px, rgba(100, 100, 225, 0.25) 720px, rgba(100, 100, 225, 0.25) 750px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 750px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 760px, rgba(100, 100, 225, 0.25) 760px, rgba(100, 100, 225, 0.25) 790px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 790px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 800px, rgba(100, 100, 225, 0.25) 800px, rgba(100, 100, 225, 0.25) 830px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 830px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 840px, rgba(100, 100, 225, 0.25) 840px, rgba(100, 100, 225, 0.25) 870px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 870px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 880px, rgba(100, 100, 225, 0.25) 880px, rgba(100, 100, 225, 0.25) 910px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 910px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 920px, rgba(100, 100, 225, 0.25) 920px, rgba(100, 100, 225, 0.25) 950px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 950px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 960px);
  background-image: linear-gradient(bottom, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) 5%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 5%), linear-gradient(left, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 0px, rgba(100, 100, 225, 0.25) 0px, rgba(100, 100, 225, 0.25) 30px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 30px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 40px, rgba(100, 100, 225, 0.25) 40px, rgba(100, 100, 225, 0.25) 70px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 70px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 80px, rgba(100, 100, 225, 0.25) 80px, rgba(100, 100, 225, 0.25) 110px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 110px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 120px, rgba(100, 100, 225, 0.25) 120px, rgba(100, 100, 225, 0.25) 150px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 150px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 160px, rgba(100, 100, 225, 0.25) 160px, rgba(100, 100, 225, 0.25) 190px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 190px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 200px, rgba(100, 100, 225, 0.25) 200px, rgba(100, 100, 225, 0.25) 230px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 230px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 240px, rgba(100, 100, 225, 0.25) 240px, rgba(100, 100, 225, 0.25) 270px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 270px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 280px, rgba(100, 100, 225, 0.25) 280px, rgba(100, 100, 225, 0.25) 310px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 310px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 320px, rgba(100, 100, 225, 0.25) 320px, rgba(100, 100, 225, 0.25) 350px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 350px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 360px, rgba(100, 100, 225, 0.25) 360px, rgba(100, 100, 225, 0.25) 390px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 390px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 400px, rgba(100, 100, 225, 0.25) 400px, rgba(100, 100, 225, 0.25) 430px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 430px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 440px, rgba(100, 100, 225, 0.25) 440px, rgba(100, 100, 225, 0.25) 470px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 470px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 480px, rgba(100, 100, 225, 0.25) 480px, rgba(100, 100, 225, 0.25) 510px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 510px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 520px, rgba(100, 100, 225, 0.25) 520px, rgba(100, 100, 225, 0.25) 550px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 550px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 560px, rgba(100, 100, 225, 0.25) 560px, rgba(100, 100, 225, 0.25) 590px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 590px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 600px, rgba(100, 100, 225, 0.25) 600px, rgba(100, 100, 225, 0.25) 630px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 630px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 640px, rgba(100, 100, 225, 0.25) 640px, rgba(100, 100, 225, 0.25) 670px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 670px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 680px, rgba(100, 100, 225, 0.25) 680px, rgba(100, 100, 225, 0.25) 710px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 710px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 720px, rgba(100, 100, 225, 0.25) 720px, rgba(100, 100, 225, 0.25) 750px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 750px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 760px, rgba(100, 100, 225, 0.25) 760px, rgba(100, 100, 225, 0.25) 790px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 790px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 800px, rgba(100, 100, 225, 0.25) 800px, rgba(100, 100, 225, 0.25) 830px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 830px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 840px, rgba(100, 100, 225, 0.25) 840px, rgba(100, 100, 225, 0.25) 870px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 870px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 880px, rgba(100, 100, 225, 0.25) 880px, rgba(100, 100, 225, 0.25) 910px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 910px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 920px, rgba(100, 100, 225, 0.25) 920px, rgba(100, 100, 225, 0.25) 950px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 950px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 960px);
  -webkit-background-size: 100% 1.5em, auto;
  -moz-background-size: 100% 1.5em, auto;
  -o-background-size: 100% 1.5em, auto;
  background-size: 100% 1.5em, auto;
  background-position: left top;
}
```

Did I do something wrong? Do Compass seriously expect people to use something as bloated as this?

Comment: I've never used the mixin but I don't think it's supposed to create that many lines of code. Are you looking for a responsive SASS/Compass library? Or just something with grids?

Comment: What were you expecting?  The default number of columns is 24, so there should be at least 24 color stops for each prefix, plus another 24 color stops for each gutter?  Your grid background isn't supposed to be something permanent.

Comment: @cimmanon I was expecting some much succinct CSS.

Comment: @djthoms I was mainly just trying out Compass, I'll certainly be using a different method to generate grids though!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a more succinct css-only solution for grid backgrounds, I'm sure we would be happy to use that instead. In the meantime, this mixin was only meant to be used as a development tool, so the answer to your question is mostly: No.

We don't expect you to use this in production. We expect you to turn it on for 5 minutes of grid debugging, then turn it back off. We also expect you to change your settings so that they give the output you want. Don't need legacy webkit gradients? [Turn them off](http://compass-style.org/reference/compass/support/).

I'm not sure what magic you expected, but 24-column striped css gradients aren't succinct. You requested that, and Compass made it happen. There will never be any output that you don't request explicitly. But *CSS is a mess*, and simple gradients have to be repeated 5 times if you want full browser support. That's why Compass exists: You don't have to write or maintain those 16000 chars by hand, and you can change them with simple settings.